# Interpreter says inconsistent indentation / usage of spaces while trying to do list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

```
def skip_elements(elements) :
    new_list = []
    for i in elements :
        if i % 2 == 0 :
            new_list= new_list.append(i)
            i+=1
        else :
             i+=1

    return new_list

print(skip_elements(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"])) # Should be ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']
print(skip_elements(['Orange', 'Pineapple', 'Strawberry', 'Kiwi', 'Peach'])) # Should be ['Orange', 'Strawberry', 'Peach']
print(skip_elements([])) # Should be []
```

Comment: You can clearly see in your code snippet above that the compiler is right. fix the line after the else statement

Comment: You're mixing tabs and spaces in your indentation. Don't do that.

Comment: Also, this isn't doing a list comprehension.

Comment: `new_list= new_list.append(i)` I believe `append` returns `None`, so you don't want to do  this.

Comment: Also, you can simply write `return elements[::2]`. Explicitly incrementing `i` does nothing, which is good because `i` is an element of the list, not an index. You would want `for i, value in enumerate(elements):`, then append `value`, not `i`. Or iterate over `range(len(elements))`, and append `elements[i]` instead of `i`.

Comment: Yes  my earlier  code returned none. Thanks for the support guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if i % 2 == 0 :
    new_list= new_list.append(i)
    i+=1
else :
     i+=1
    ^ extra space - you might want to use tabs instead of spaces when it comes to python - or any language for that matter
```

---

```
new_list = new_list.append(i)
```

`.append()` will return `None`. Replace it with:

```
new_list.append(i)
```

---

Finally, it's a lot of effort to return a list with all the *odd* elements. You can simply do (thanks to [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63061614/python-compiler-says-inconsistent-indentation-usage-of-spaces-while-trying-to-d/63061794#comment111516038_63061614)):

```
def skip_elements(elements):
    return elements[::2]
```